# rpy2 installation on Mac OSX

Tags: python, r, installation, mac

I'm desperatly trying and retrying to install rpy2 on my Mac OS 10.6 in order to run SDA4PP plugin on QGIS.
My version of R is 2.14.0 and it was obviously compiled with the option *--enable-R-shlib* since, as I read on a forum, all files in /library/Frameworks/R.framework/Libraries/ share the extension ".dylib".
When I run `easy_install rpy2` on the Terminal, here is what I get:

```
Searching for rpy2
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/
Reading http://rpy.sourceforge.net
Best match: rpy2 2.2.6
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.2.6.tar.gz#md5=32d73a3e4acb915ce15d958c9092dcb8
Processing rpy2-2.2.6.tar.gz
Running rpy2-2.2.6/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/5L/5Li0yCI7EqmkqJ+Ra--M9U+++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-71n22e/rpy2-2.2.6/egg-dist-tmp-s83lG5
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 142: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 143: make: command not found
R was not built as a library
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install-2.6", line 10, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c9', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1671, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1659, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1675, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 211, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 446, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 476, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 655, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 930, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 919, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 27, in run_setup
    lambda: execfile(
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 63, in run
    return func()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 29, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "setup.py", line 462, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 167, in run
    self.run_command("egg_info")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 333, in run_command
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 177, in run
    self.find_sources()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 252, in find_sources
    mm.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 306, in run
    self.add_defaults()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 330, in add_defaults
    sdist.add_defaults(self)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/command/sdist.py", line 300, in add_defaults
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 319, in get_finalized_command
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 117, in ensure_finalized
  File "setup.py", line 155, in finalize_options
  File "setup.py", line 319, in get_rconfig
  File "setup.py", line 279, in from_string
ValueError: Invalid substring

in string
```

It says hat R was not built as a library but seems to continue anyway. What does that mean ? 
What should I do ?

Thanks for your help.

stan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem seems to hinted at by:

> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 142: make: command not found

You need developers tools (make, gcc, etc...). On OS X you need to register on the Apple site in order to be able to download and install them, AFAIR.

Comment: Thanks! I've installed Xcode3 and tryed again. This time I could read a long list of warnings starting with `warning: no previously-included files matching 'patch' found anywhere in distribution`; ending with `./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c: In function ‘EmbeddedR_ChooseFile’: ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:646: warning: ‘gstate’ may be used uninitialized in this function lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/5L/5Li0yCI7EqmkqJ+Ra--M9U+++TI/-Tmp-//ccQiCvrB.out (No such file or directory) error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1`. Any idea?

Comment: Got a similar result installing manually **rpy2-2.2.6.tar.gz** through `python setup.py install`. I'm looking for a **.dmg** file...

Comment: It might be that the latest OS X releases are compiling for LLVM (and the code base is giving it trouble). Someone else with a similar problem here ? May be worth bumping the question onto the rpy mailing-list ?

Comment: I've just posted the problem on **rpy-list**. Thanks